# Can not watch list 'matrix'

Tags: python, function, class, class-method

I have a problem with class "CellList", so I want to print list "matrix". But when I print this list, my Pycharm display "[[myfile.Cell object at 0x0034...][myfile.Cell object at 0x0034...],...]"

```
class Cell:

    def __init__(self, row: int, col: int, state=0):
        self.state = state
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

    def is_alive(self) -> bool:
        return self.state


class CellList():

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:

            r = 0
            matrix = []

            for line in f:
                c = 0
                arr = []
                for ch in line:
                    if ch == '0' or ch == '1':
                        arr.append(Cell(r, c, int(ch)))
                    c += 1
                matrix.append(arr)
                r += 1

        cls.r_max = r
        cls.c_max = c - 1
        cls.matrix = matrix

        return CellList(cls.r_max, cls.c_max, cls.matrix)
```

Comment: you have to implement `__repr__` in your `Cell` class.

Answer (score 0):

in order for an object to represent itself in a non-default way, you have to imprelemnt a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) method. this could be that method:

```
class Cell:
    # ....
    def __repr__(self):
        # python >= 3.6
        return f'Cell(state={self.state}, row={self.row}, col={self.col})'
        # python < 3.6
        # return 'Cell(state={0.state}, row={0.row}, col={0.col})'.format(self)
```

and while you are at it you might also implement `__str__` (in the same way?).